# How to show Youtube videos at my blog and hide on Youtube.com

Tags: youtube

I want to record screen casts and video lectures, upto one hour each to upload to Youtube. If I add these video on my blog using Youtube script, it displays at Youtube.com too. What I want is, my video/casts should not be visible/searchable at Youtube.com, so that users must have to come at my blog to watch them?

Is there a way to do so? Is is a paid service or free?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about YouTube use and YouTube policy, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to have youtube host hour content but deliberately trying to "hide" it on Youtube violates their ToS.